# read from conf file in python3 and modify it

Tags: python, scripting

```
[building1] {
  floors = 7
  occupied_floors = 5
  [floor:1] {
    [section1] {
      total_flat = 50
      occupied = 2
    }
    [section2] {
      total_flat = 50
      occupied = 5
    }
  }
}
```

How can I parse this file?

I tried

```
config=configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('myfile')
```

I get below error

```
MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
```

Comment: Where this file comes from? It's some mix of json and ini

Comment: This is not a standard configuration file. Also this is not a proper JSON. You need to structure the data properly.

Comment: Yes, this is the predefined file we have which I need to parse. Is there a way to build a custom parser if yes can you share some input?